# It is possible to download files via HTTP/HTTPS using SDL_Net?

Tags: http, sdl-net

I'm making an SDL2/OpenGL game with big assets. Some platforms, like android, limit app package size hard, so I want to download them separately. I'll also meet this issue when try to make downloadable content.

I want to make game as portable as possible, so SDL_net as networking library is my choice. Is it possible to download big (500MB+) files with it and how? Are there any good tutorials about it?

Comment: I can't really help you on that, but the RAM of a phone is even more limited. Modern phones only have 2-3GB. Also because the package size is limited I doubt that you can ditch that by downloading.

Comment: @user11914177 I will store them on SD/Internal memory of course, that would be silly to download assets every time you need them and store them in RAM.

Comment: I thought that was limited. But I don't know anything about android.